# Approximation for spring pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, spring

In this post,

[Approximations for a spring pendulum's equations of motion in 2D](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/320035/)

I get the most of it, but the simple one.
I don't quite understand why we can approximate $l+a \sim l$

Without the approximation,

$k a = m g \cos \theta$

Therefore,

$ a = \frac{mg}{k} \cos \theta,$

which means in small angle approximation, when $\theta \rightarrow 0$, $r$ becomes constant, not 0.

Comment: What is $r$? I don’t see it on that page.

Comment: @Chemomechanics

My bad, it should have been $a$. I edited my post. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The approximation is appropriate only if $\frac{mg}{k}\ll l$. If it’s not, the approximation is invalid. This is a separate assumption from the assumption of small $\theta$. Does this resolve the issue?

Comment: @Chemomechanics 
So, the small angle approximation(or small amplitude) itself does not guarantee that $l + a \sim l$.
Is that right?

Comment: Of course not; consider a motionless but compliant spring.

Comment: @Chemomechanics
Thanks for the clarification. In the solution manual, without saying anything other than small angle approximation, it just assumes that $l+a \sim l$ (Just like the writer did in the original post). So I was a little bit confused.

Comment: $~l+a=l\left( 1+\dfrac{a}{l}\right) \approx l~, \frac al\ll ~1 $

Comment: @Eli
What's the justification to say $\frac{a}{l} \ll 1$?

Comment: @TerryCho  take $~\frac al=0.001~$ thus you obtain $~1+0.001\approx 1$

Comment: @Eli ...? why...?